# Trying to decrypt a string using array of characters(Polybius Square)

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption

I'm new to stackoverflow as well as Java programming. I have made a program that currently encrypts a string of characters using the array `polybiusSquare`.

The array is as shown:

```
static char polybiusSquare[][] = { { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' }, 
                                   { 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M' },
                                   { 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' }, 
                                   { 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y' }, 
                                   { 'Z', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'N' },
                                   { 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'N', 'M' } };
```

For information purposes if "hello" was encrypted using this I would the string received back would be "2215252532". This has been done based on the coordinates for the 2D array.

I am now stuck as now I need to somehow be able to decrypt the string back into normal characters by passing the string of numbers into the array.

Any help would be much appreciated and my apologies if I have posted this in the wrong place or made anything unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrypting just means running over the result string and extracting the indices:

```
private static final char polybiusSquare[][] = { 
    { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' },
    { 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M' },
    { 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S' },
    { 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y' },
    { 'Z', 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'N' },
    { 'E', 'T', 'A', 'O', 'N', 'M' } 
};

public static String decrypt (String crypt) {
    int len = crypt.length(); 
    StringBuilder plain = new StringBuilder (len / 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        int rowIndex = crypt.charAt(i) - '0' - 1;
        int colIndex = crypt.charAt(i + 1) - '0' - 1;
        plain.append(polybiusSquare[rowIndex][colIndex]);
    }

    return plain.toString();
}
```

Note that this example code doesn't contain any input validation, for brevity's sake. In a real solution, you may want to be a bit more defensive.

Comment: Hi Mureinik, when trying to test your code, i am having errors with crypt.length due to it not being an int. Should it be an int or am I doing something wrong?.

Comment: I've been looking into this a bit more. It seems i am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in this line: 'plain.append(polybiusSquare[rowIndex][colIndex]);'

Comment: Also im assuming the method needs to return a string?

Comment: @Kallendo96 it should indeed return a `String`. What input gives you this exception? The code runs perfectly with your example input of `"2215252532"`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm being a complete idiot and was trying to decipher a string that said "hello". Thanks for your help now I really appreciate it.